# No Docs For RecyclerViewAdapter for cloud FireStore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am actually working on an app project which uses cloud firestore and I am not able to find any proper docs on FirestoreRecycler Adapter I would be very humbled if you could guide me in the right direction.**

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have visited these resources if not then you should.
You can also use the native Recyclerview and fill up items using data from firebase.

Using RecyclerView Adapter [Github](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)

Using Cloud Firestore [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)